# Bayesian use of previous experiments

Tags: bayesian

Assume I have two studies, say $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$, with respective datasets $\mathcal{D}_1, \mathcal{D}_2$, parameters $\theta^{(1)}, \theta^{(2)}$ and response variables $y, z$. I have the following questions:

1. If I am interested in using the response $y$ from the first study as a covariate in the second study, which is a recommended way in which I could proceed? Would it make sense to have a Normal approximation to the posterior predictive and calculate the mean and variance and use this as a prior for the parameter related to the covariate $y$, say $\theta_y^{(2)}$, in the second study? The main issue that I have with this is that the posterior distribution that I have does not seem Normal.
2. Moreover, assume that $\mathcal{D}_2$ has a set of covariates that appear in $\mathcal{D}_1$. Which is the recommended way to proceed if I would like to include the posterior information about the subset of $\theta^{(1)}$ in the second study $\mathcal{S}_2$?

Comment: Your notation is somewhat confusing ($\theta^{(1)}\overset{?}{=} \theta_1$, $\theta^{(2)}\overset{?}{=} \theta^{(2)}_y$), might benefit from some clean-up. Also, if the posterior is not normal, what stops you from summarizing it with another, more suitable distribution?

Comment: I have done some cleanup. $\theta_1$ should have read $\theta^{(1)}$. Since I want to use $y$ as a covariate in the second study, I have denoted the parameter associated to $y$ treated as a covariate as $\theta_y^{(2)}$. I could use another distribution as you mention but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. I am also interested in what is the practical way others in the community have done it.

Comment: This kind of problem is better handled through joint modeling of all datasets combined than by using priors, usually.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @FrankHarrell. Do you have an idea where I can find a paper or example where it is done in the way that you mention?

Comment: Here are simple examples: https://fharrell.com/post/hxcontrol but I wish I had my hands on one that was for a regular prediction task.  The main idea would be to let two or more datasets share parameters that you have strong information should be the sample (e.g., slopes but not intercepts) and when you think one dataset may be estimating a parameter that is different from what another dataset is estimating, put add a bias parameter to absorb this difference; put a prior on the amount of bias.  If your prior has infinite variance that may mean that one data source is being ignored.